# About salesforce sites question

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com

facing a issue about salesforce site. In my sandbox org, i create a site web page and working fine for test some business process. but, after i refresh full sandbox, i found that the site configuration is not exit. but, the url still can access. I am trying to clear cache and re-login again, still see this URL can access. after i search google, but, i don't get any anwser. If you know it , please tell me. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh a sandbox from production, pages from production should appear in the sandbox.  If you are able to access a Site.com page or a Site in the sandbox that does not exist then you should open a case with Salesforce.com support to get further assistance.

There is [caching for guest users](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_website_delete.htm&language=en_US), but that doesn't seem right. I'd expect the Site or pages to be unreachable if they don't exist.